# Dynamically get the color based on column available in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having a table which unique color range per product and need to get the color based on available quantity point in time.

Can you please help to get the color dynamically per product

```
create table test
(
    Product varchar(200)
    , Quantity int
    , RangeRed  varchar(200)
    , RangeYellow   varchar(200)
)

insert into test select 'A',10, '{value 1} <=5', '({value1} >5) and ({value1} <=10)'
insert into test select 'B',20, '{value 1} <=5', '({value1} >5) and ({value1} <=20)'
insert into test select 'C',50, '{value 1} <=5', '({value1} >5) and ({value1} <=10)'
insert into test select 'D',5, '{value 1} <=5', '({value1} >5) and ({value1} <=10)'

select Product, Quantity, case when RangeRed then 'Red' when RangeYellow then 'Yellow' else 'white' end as Color
select Product, Quantity,  
    Replace(RangeRed, '{value1}','Quantity')   as RangeRed
    , Replace(RangeYellow, '{value1}','Quantity')  as RangeYellow
from   test
) x
```

Expected Output :

[image]

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use dynamic SQL for this. A simple example follows, but you might want to improve it.

Note this is using the hacky form of concatenating the results from multiple rows into a single output. There are better ways to do it which I leave as an exercise for you.

There will be a solution which doesn't require `union`ing all the rows together, but it would require building a dynamic case expression to evaluate the condition for each product.

```
create table #test
(
    Product varchar(200)
    , Quantity int
    , RangeRed  varchar(200)
    , RangeYellow   varchar(200)
)

insert into #test (Product, Quantity, RangeRed, RangeYellow)
values ('A', 10, '{Value1} <= 5', '({Value1} >5) and ({Value1} <=10)'),
('B', 20, '{Value1} <=5', '({Value1} >5) and ({Value1} <=20)'),
('C', 50, '{Value1} <=5', '({Value1} >5) and ({Value1} <=10)'),
('D', 5, '{Value1} <=5', '({Value1} >5) and ({Value1} <=10)')

declare @Sql nvarchar(max) = '';

select @Sql = @Sql + case when @Sql = '' then '' else ' union all ' end + 'select Product, Quantity, case when ' + replace(RangeRed,'{Value1}','Quantity') + ' then ''Red'' when ' + replace(RangeYellow,'{Value1}','Quantity') + ' then ''Yellow'' else ''White'' end Color from #test where Product = ''' + Product + '''' from #Test;

-- print @Sql; -- Debugging

exec (@Sql);
```

Returns:

```
Product Quantity    Colour
A       10          Yellow
B       20          Yellow
C       50          White
D       5           Red
```